# How to edit inline css of a div in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this :

```
<div class="imgarea product_image preload" style="opacity: 0; ">
```

I want to change opacity:0 to opacity:1

I have tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.imgarea.product_image.preload"').removeAttr('style') 
});
```

I'm trying to remove style, or to change it to opacity:1, because image don't shows up.

Please help

Comment: You have to document your question a bit more. What have you tried? What are you actually trying to do? What's the problem? Is it hardcore coding, or editing the CSS of a post/page?

Comment: I have tried this :

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.imgarea.product_image.preload"').removeAttr('style')
 });

I'm trying to remove style, or to change it to opacity:1, because image don't shows up.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean you could do this with jquery

```
   $('.imgarea.product_image.preload').css('opacity', 1);
```

Edit: i forgot the dot before imgarea. You can test it here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Vwevs/

Comment: forgot a dot before the classname.

Comment: did you check the link i pasted in my answer. It works perfectly, can you show me your entire code?

Comment: Krike's answer works.

What I see in the original code is an extra double quote after preload.  Try removing that quote.